# Injecting extenal location source data into Google Play Location Service: how?

Tags: android, google-maps, bluetooth, gps, google-play-services

Is it possible using the Google Play Location Service to inject location objects which are received through an external Bluetooth GPS Receiver which is connected to the smartphone?

I would like to use the Google Play Location service as the only service to retrieve location objects (longitude, latitude, altitude) within my code in several places without cluttering the code to fetch Location data from different sources. I am more than happy when the Location Service can do that for me instead of "merging" these objects from different places.

Is it possible? And if so, how?

Link to Google Play Location Service: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

If not, what are the alternatives besides hacking your own code to merge location objects from Location service or external Bluetooth device into one "service" within the code?

Answer (score 0):

how about using master key vulnerability  and install an app in the root and hide it.i think below link will explain more about it.

[link](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/164134-how-bitcoin-thieves-used-an-android-flaw-to-steal-money-and-how-it-affects-everyone-else)